# Making accordion with setting up the scrollTop - offset animation 0 on click... doesn't work well when data is expened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making accordions with setting up the scrollTop - offset animation 0 on click..

everything works fine if all are closed before click to expend. But if any tab data is expended specially top accordions.... scrollTop code push the entire content up and hide into top window area...

And i want to reset the default position when all tabs are closed.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

here is the code and fiddle URL:

http://jsfiddle.net/mufeedahmad/SKB3Z/10/

```
var showContainer = $('ul#ui-collapsible div.collapsible-content'), 
    showClickHandler = $('ul#ui-collapsible li > a');

    $.fn.offsetscroll = function(){
        $(this).click(function(){    
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
                }, 500);
                return false;
            });
    }
    showClickHandler.offsetscroll();        

    $.fn.myClickMethod = function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.parent().hasClass('active')){          
            $this.parent().removeClass('active');           
            $this.next().slideUp();         
                }
                else{
                    $('ul#ui-collapsible .active').removeClass('active');           
                    showContainer.slideUp();
                    $this.next().slideDown(500);
                    $this.parent().addClass('active');
                    }
        }
        showClickHandler.click(function(){
                $(this).myClickMethod();             

        });
```

Comment: the question is not clear.. Could you explain little bit more..?

Comment: if you see the fiddle URL and play with the accordions....
on every click each accordion has to assign scrollTop offset 0... which is working... but if in case of expended form specially top accordions it doesn't work... it actually push the content extreme top of the window or hide the content... instead should be upfront like... hope this makes you clear....

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).scrollTop()
```

instead of

```
scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
```

this will solve your problem.